# Deploy docker windows container from CI to Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-deployment, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to wrap my head around Docker containers, specifically how to deploy them to a Docker container host. I know there are lots of options here and ultimately we'll switch to a more common deployment approach (e.g. to Azure, AWS) but this is a temporary requirement. We're using windows containers.

I have a container image that I've created and will be recreated on each build as part of a Jenkins job (our Jenkins instance is hosted on a container-ready windows server 2016 box). I also have a separate container-ready Windows Server 2016 box which is where we intend to run the containers from.

However, I'm not sure how I can have the containers that our Jenkins box produces automatically pushed to our separate 2016 host. Ideally, I'd like to avoid using a container registry, unless there is a low-friction, on-premise option available.

Comment: Maybe a stupid idea, but what about some script which just copies the content over the network and an running agent on the server which starts the container when it registers new content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container registries are the way to distribute Docker images. Tooling is built around registries, it would be counterproductive to work against the concept.

But `docker image save` and `docker image import` could get you started as it saves the image as a tar file that you can transfer between the hosts. Once you copied the image to the other box, you can start it up with the usual `docker run` command, or `docker compose up`.

If your case is not trivial though and you start having multiple Docker hosts to run the containers, container orchestrators like Docker Swarm, Kubernetes are the way to go - or the managed versions of those, like Azure ACS. That rabbit hole is deeper though than I can answer in a single SO answer :)